# Name for function in big O but not in little o?

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

Let $f(n) = O(g(n))$, but not $f(n) = o(g(n))$. That's a nice property, because it means that we cannot replace $g(n)$ with a substantially smaller function. **Is there a name** for this choice of $g(n)$?

Obviously this covers more cases than just $f(n) = \Theta (g(n))$. It requires the existence of $c > 0$ such that $f(n)\geq cg(n)$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Informally, it's a *asymptotically tight upper bound*, though this phrase also has different meanings.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the distinction between this concept and $\Theta$, I'm not quite getting it. Do you mean "for infinitely many $n$" as opposed to "for all $n > n_0$"?